# What's this parasite?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, parasitology, herpetology

Any microbiologists or parasitologists recognize this? It's from my pet bearded dragon in the eastern US and the vet's never seen it before.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should include: 1) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 2) habitat information — e.g. from what type of lizard and from where in/on the organism it was isolated; and 3) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

It could be a whipworm, a common parasite in dogs with a flagellum.
Check the image here:

**Image at:**
https://www.texaswestveterinarian.com/whipworms/

Comment: Thanks. Afraid it's probably not that. What my lizard has is microscopic, whipworms are 3-5 cm.